# Table.Edit forcing Cursor to the EOF

Tags: delphi

Can someone please tell me why this only works one time after the aTbl.Edit.
If I rem out the four lines for editing the table it iterates through all 49 records. It seems that the Edit and Post will position the file-cursor at the end of the file as I am only ever getting one record changed and it quits with the EOF.

I am using D5, Zeos-6 and SQLite3. I even tried grabbing the Auto-inc before the edit and then a Locate after it, but it still quits after the edit.

Thanks for anything you can suggest, but this has been driving me nuts all afternoon. I keep thinking it is something stupid I have done, but I cannot find it. :)

```
aTbl.First;                            // Test DB has 49 records
while not aTbl.EOF do
begin
  for i := 0 to lbCt.Items.Count-1 do  // Currently only two items in the list
  begin                                // and only the second makes a match
    aMatch := False;                   // which then forces the edit
    CtStr := lbCt.Items[i]);
    case InOut.ItemIndex of
      0: aMatch := aTbl.FieldByName(fld_A).AsString = CtStr;
      1: aMatch := aTbl.FieldByName(fld_B).AsString = CtStr;
      2: aMatch := (aTbl.FieldByName(fld_A).AsString = CtStr) or
                   (aTbl.FieldByName(fld_B).AsString = CtStr);
      3: aMatch := (aTbl.FieldByName(fld_A).AsString = CtStr) and
                   (aTbl.FieldByName(fld_B).AsString = CtStr);
    end;
    if aMatch then
    begin
      aTbl.Edit; 
      aTbl.FieldByName('Account').AsString := lbCt.Items[i];
      aTbl.FieldByName('Folder').AsString := lbCt.Items[i];
      aTbl.Post;
    end;
  end;
  aTbl.Next;
end;
```

Comment: Um.. @TLama what did you have to edit?

Comment: You're welcome. :-) I've posted an answer, so that others that find this question can see it. (As far as the rep thing, I just posted the link based on what @TLama had posted to explain it. Now that I look, though, you have in fact accepted 7 answers for the 9 questions you'd received answers on (that's the "green tick" you mention - you accept an answer by clicking the check to turn it green), so I think you're doing fine.)

Comment: 's OK, @TLama, I just could not figure out what I might have done wrong. :) Well, other than code formatting which is ***very** personal and I have been doing that my-way for almost 40 years. It's all good though, I don't get antsy over edits. Now that Ken has explained how to see what was done maybe sometimes, I can learn from the editing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is most likely that you have an index active that uses either `Account` or `Folder` as one of the index fields. Those are the fields you're changing the value of, and if either of them is in the current index expression it will move the record pointer to the new location for the row (which might in fact be `EOF`).

Comment: Actually Ken, there was an Index active but it was on nether of the fields being edited. An idiosyncrasy of the Zeos or SQLite I guess. But -- it is all working now, thanks again.